# SharePoint Incoming Email auto-adding a CC

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

SharePoint 2010.  We have an incoming SP email address for a list (invoices@company.com).  When an email is sent to this address, we are seeing it arrive with a CC automatically added (testuser@company.com).  I looked but can't find anything in SP or our Exchange server that would automatically add a CC to an incoming email.  I'm hoping I'm just not looking in the right place.

Any suggestions where to look?  Thanks!

Comment: Outlook client rules can do that. Check the clients of the guys that set up that account. It is fairly common to do a CC like that during dev so you get a copy of the email and can see what SP did.

Comment: That's what I thought. Now to figure out what account it might be since it was setup many years ago and we've had a lot of turnover. ;). Thanks!